# Работа с почтой яндекса на python

Tags: python, imap

Нужно выгрузить все адреса за последний месяц которым были отправлены письма.
По IMAP получаю список всех папок, но папки названные кириллицой имеют имена по типу `&BB4EQgQ,BEAEMAQyBDsENQQ9BD0ESwQ1-`
Как их перекодировать что бы можно было прочитатать?

Answer (score 2):

Гугл привёл на [соседний SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776679/imap-folder-path-encoding-imap-utf-7-for-python), в котором говорится, что эта кодировка называется **IMAP UTF-7**.

Там же говорится, что декодировать можно с помощью [IMAPClient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/IMAPClient/1.0.2):

```
from imapclient import imap_utf7
s = b'&BB4EQgQ,BEAEMAQyBDsENQQ9BD0ESwQ1-'  # Важно: bytes, а не str
result = imap_utf7.decode(s)
print(result)  # => Отправленные
```

Comment: Очевидно я ошибся.. спасибо :)